# How to set the background color of a specific component in solid-js and Tailwind CSS?

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, solid-js

I set the background color of my solid-js application to gray in my `index.css` file. However, I would like my `<App/>` component to have a white background unlike the other components. I have written
the following code:

```
    function App() {
      if (document.querySelector('.App')) {
        document.querySelector('.App').style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
      }
      
      useNetworkStatus();
      return (
        <div class="App">
        </div>
      );
    }
```

But that didn't work, so I changed my code to:

```
    if (document.querySelector('.App')) {
       document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#e1e1e1"
    }
```

But instead all of the components of my solid-js application no longer have a gray background color, but are instead white except for the `<App/>` component which kept its gray color (this is the one I wanted to switch to a white background).

Here is the content of my [index.css](https://gist.github.com/gouneken/fad8e1e89f4d332cea2dcf988debd999) file. As I explained earlier, I just want the component
`<App/>` to have a white background color unlike the others. I'm waiting impatiently for your answers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the imperative API, just use the style prop on the element itself:

```js
function Component() {
  return (
    <div style={{['background-color']: '#e1e1e1'}}>
      Some Custom Component
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unlike React, Solid uses kebab-case property names as in `['background-color']` in its style props.

You can also use css classes to style a component using `class` prop on the element:

```js
function Component() {
  return (
    <div class="bg some-class">
      Some Custom Component
    </div>
  );
}
```